# CS50 blur filter(less)

Tags: c, cs50

`The image comes out as static with various colours instead of a blur where you can still see the image, can't find the bug`

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width]){
RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];

int pixle1;
int pixle2;
int pixle3;

//copy original image to copy
            for(int f = 0; f < height; f++){
                for(int b = 0; b < width; b++){
                copy[f][b] = image[f][b];
            }
        }

//go through each pixel at i's row and j's column
            for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < width; j++){
//make boundaries surrounding the original pixel to iterate through
for(int x = i - 1; x <= i + 1 && x >= 0; x++){
    for(int y = j + 1; y <= j + 1 && y >= 0; y++){
//add the RGB values to later use to find the average
            pixle1 = pixle1 + copy[x][y].rgbtRed;
            pixle2 = pixle2 + copy[x][y].rgbtGreen;
            pixle3 = pixle3 + copy[x][y].rgbtBlue;
    }
//find the average of the pixels surrounding the original and original pixel
//then add that average to original pixel to create a blur

                     image[i][j].rgbtRed = round((pixle1) / 9.0);

                     image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round((pixle2) / 9.0);

                     image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round((pixle3) / 9.0);
    // 'And then read pixels’ colours from a copy but write (i.e., change) pixels’ colours in the image?'


}
                }
         }
   return;
    }
```

**it blurs a bmp file and for each pixel, I find all the pixels surrounding the copied 2d array it and find the average from them all including the main pixel and then add that to the image 2d array which has a struct data type **
*italiwedfewfEWFEfc*

> qugewGEWGEote

Comment: out of bounds in copy

Comment: wouldn't the "&& x >= 0" and "&& y >= 0" catch it being out of bounds?

Comment: You must set `pixle1 = pixle2 = pixle3 = 0;` before the start of the `x` and `y` pair of loops.

Comment: How would these conditions avoid accessing the array beyond its limits? There is no upper bounds check.

Comment: Also, these conditions would make you terminate the loop instead of skipping a single pixel.

Comment: *wouldn't the "&& x >= 0" and "&& y >= 0" catch it being out of bounds?* No, because it isn't testing the "coordinate + offset" sum.

Comment: In total, `x` will go up to `height+1` with is 2 beyond the maximum. Similar for `y` but there you already start at `j+1` instead of `j-1`

Comment: You should think again how you must handle edge or corner pixels.

Comment: Thank you all for the help, I was able to get my program working!